# How to redirect entire website on HTTPS except 2 subdirectories?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, https

I would like to redirect my entire site to start with HTTPS except 2 subdirectories that I wish to keep on HTTP.

I tried the following but to no avail. Please advice.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/north/index.html$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/south/index.html$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Comment: what to you mean **to no avail**? what exactly is happening or not happening? Does it not redirect at all? More details

Comment: @Panama Jack, everything redirects to HTTPS. I just wish to keep the subdirectories, example.com/north/index.html on HTTP. what's wrong?

Comment: Keep the first condition just as: `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/north/`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try and have you rules like this

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(north|south)(/.*)? [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Hi Panama Jack and Anubhava, thanks for your advice! It works! :)